# Direct super call is illegal in non-constructor, use super."constructor"() instead

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

- I am new to react am trying to write a simple click event functionality.
- When I click choice the span tag with this class name
- I wrote a small prototype in codepen and its working fine there...
- but if i incorporate the same code in my codebase its throwing an error...
- do you guys know what is the problem
- even in codepen it shows the error 
  unknown: super() outside of class constructor (16:8)

**working small prototype code** 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxPvyr?editors=0110

**actual code base trying to fix the error**
http://codepen.io/kk-/pen/BjeLry

```
Line 16: Direct super call is illegal in non-constructor, use super."constructor"() instead
  14 | 
  15 |     constructor(props) {
> 16 |         super(props);
     |         ^
  17 |         
  18 |         this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

Comment: Why are you defining a `constructor` when using `React.createClass`? The `createClass` pattern does autobinding for you.

Comment: @mathletics thanks for your reply...can you update in codepen its so confusing :(

Comment: Read the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html; you are conflating the ES6 Class pattern with the React Factory pattern.

Comment: @mathletics i am reading it...it would be great if you update the codepen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple idomatic ways to define a React class - it's possible you were mixing and matching styles, which of course is not supported:

---

**ES5** - No `constructor()` method, use `getInitialState()`

```
var React = require('react');

var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { message: 'hello world'};
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.state.message}</div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = SomeComponent;
```

---

**ES6** - No `getInitialState()`, use `constructor()` Also, you *must* call `super(props)` before invoking `this`!

```
import React from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state({
            message: 'hello world'
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.state.message}</div>
        );
    }
}

SomeComponent.propTypes = {};

export default SomeComponent;
```

**UPDATE**: If one forgets to call `super(props)` in `constructor()`, but then attempts to access `this`, the following error will be thrown: `'this' is not allowed before super()`:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/_workspaces/hello-world/some-component.jsx: 'this' is not allowed before super()
  20 | class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  21 |     constructor(props) {
> 22 |         this.state = {
     |         ^
  23 |             message: 'hello world'
  24 |         }
  25 |     }
```

Here's a little more info on why it's required: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/should-we-include-the-props-parameter-to-class-constructors-when-declaring-components-using-es6-classes/2781

---

**ES6 Static** No internal methods, just an implied `render()`

```
import React from 'react';

const SomeComponent = ({
    message
}) => (
    <div>{message}</div>
);

SomeComponent.propTypes = {};

export default SomeComponent;
```

Comment: @texirv No problem, and don't let the mods beat you down. We've all been there...they just seem to forget sometimes...

Comment: i have one more question what would happen if we dont  call super(props) in es6

Comment: @texirv Great question, I've updated the answer to address this point.