# How to pass a variable inside a component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component:

```
const Rec = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.PureRenderMixin],
    renderText() {
        if (hidden) {
            req_link = <Link to={`/rec/edit`} style={st}>Request link</Link>
        }
        else {
            request_link = null   
        }

        return (
             <div> {request_link} </div>
        );
    },

    fields() {
        ....
        if (fieldID == "hidden") {
              var hidden = true;
        } else {
              var hidden = false;
        }
        return (
              <div> other stuff....  </div>
        );
   },
});
```

`renderText()` should show a link if the value of `hidden` is true, and value for this variable can only be set in `fields()`. So how can I pass `hidden` from `fields()` to `renderText()`?

Comment: Can you share us the complete code, especially the render function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a state variable and monitor that variable as shown in the below code

```
const Rec = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {hidden: false};
  }
  renderText: function() {
        if (this.state.hidden) {
            req_link = <Link to={`/rec/edit`} style={st}>Request link</Link>
        }
        else {
            request_link = null   
        }

        return (
             <div> {request_link} </div>
        );
    },

    fields: function() {
        ....

        if (fieldID == "hidden") {
             this.setState({hidden: true});
        } else {
              this.setState({hidden: false});
        }
        return (
              <div> other stuff....  </div>
        );
   },
});
```

ES6 script format

```
export default class Rec extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {hidden: false};
    }
  renderText = () =>{
        if (this.state.hidden) {
            req_link = <Link to={`/rec/edit`} style={st}>Request link</Link>
        }
        else {
            request_link = null   
        }

        return (
             <div> {request_link} </div>
        );
    }

    fields = () => {
        ....

        if (fieldID == "hidden") {
             this.setState({hidden: true});
        } else {
              this.setState({hidden: false});
        }
        return (
              <div> other stuff....  </div>
        );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham, it works! But I'm getting this warning: `warning.js:44Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render' or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to 'componentWillMount'.` How can I fix it?

Comment: where are you calling the function fields from

Comment: There is another function named `renderBlock()` that is calling `fields()` through a `map`.

Comment: One more question, I read somewhere that `getInitialState` is deceased now we declare all state as a simple initialisation property in the constructor (https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/). So I guess I need to change the code again....

Comment: @Sarah  I edited the ans to substitute the getInitialState with constructor. I also came across the warning that you got as soon as I remember I will reply the solution to that

Comment: No, the ES6 version doesn't work :( I'm getting this error: " `super() outside of class constructor` ". I tried passing `props` like: `constructor(props)` and `super(props)` but still getting the same error. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492976/direct-super-call-is-illegal-in-non-constructor-use-super-constructor-inste]  

It may sound silly but is it related to `Rec` component declaration? I didn't change it like what you wrote in your ES6 sample code. It's like " `const Rec = React.createClass({` " in my code!

Comment: Ok yes, it was because of the component declaration!! :-P It works now! Thanks Shubham :)